# Adding a class to an unpublished item in 2sxc list

Tags: 2sxc

Is there an way to add a class to an item if it is set to unpublished? So if I have a list of items the unpublished ones are visible to admin only but would be good yo be able to highlight them so the user can easily see which are not published.

This is a situation where the toolbar is not visible on the list view, only on the details view of the APP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there is a property called IsPublished which you can use for this.